# Adding JQuery tooltip using css class instead of id 

Tags: java, jquery, css, jsp

Am having problem displaying tooltip. Am having an  tag in a jsp which will load multiple times in a dashboard jsp. If i try this with id only one component is displaying tooltip.I want to to do it using css class. The code is as follows,

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
        .tooltip({
            showURL: false
        });
    });
     </script>
```

and my  tag looks like this,

```
<a cssClass="customToolTip" title="My Sample <br> tooltip </a>
```

The code that works with id(for 1 instance) looks as follows,

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#sample').tooltip({
            showURL: false
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So using with class you could do:

```
//your anchor tag
<a class="customToolTip" title="My Sample">tooltip</a>

$(function() { $('.customToolTip').tooltip({ showURL: false }); });
```

Comment: I had tried that but still it's not working. Class selector works fine for one element but am having multiple elements with same scenario on my dashboard. I too still don't know y it is not working. Any other ways to solve it.